# how to minify sencha touch project using ant?

Tags: ant, sencha-touch-2

I am working on sencha touch application. I tried to build as a native app using phonegap. but the touch library itself taking more than 10 MB. Is it possible to minify it using ant?

Answer (score 2):

[Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) uses Ant under the hood to minify a "build" directory for your app - which you could then drop into PhoneGap.

In Touch 2.3, there's a [whole guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/cordova) on PhoneGap integration via Sencha Cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I use [HtmlCompressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) for minify html with Ant before build. Part of my [build.xml](https://github.com/petrkle/tabulka/blob/master/build.xml#L57):

```
<target name="-pre-build">
 <ant target="compress-html" />
</target>

<target name="compress-html">
 <echo>Compressing html</echo>
  <exec executable="java" dir="." failonerror="true">
  <arg line="-jar ${user.home}/lib/htmlcompressor-1.5.3.jar --compress-js -r -m '*.html' -o assets/www/ assets/www/" />
</exec>
</target>
```